# nginx reverse proxy with subpath

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I built a web app that will listen on a port and handle HTTP requests. For example, if I run it locally at `127.0.0.1:3000`. I can access it with `http://127.0.0.1:3000/path/within/app` on my browser. I would like to deploy it on one of my servers, which is configured with `nginx` to handle all incoming requests (and TLS) and forward them to different applications (listening at `http://127.0.0.1:xxx`). Normally, I would give each app a different subdomain (e.g., access `app1` with `app1.example.com` and `app2` with `app2.example.com`), but it would be more convenient if I can use subpath (e.g., access `app1` with `example.com/app1` and `app2` with `example.com/app2`). But I am not sure how to configure it.

My current configuration file is like the following. Suppose my app is listening at `127.0.0.1:3000`.

```
location ^~ /app1 {
    proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header    Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect      off;
    proxy_pass          http://127.0.0.1:3000/;
}
```

I would like to achieve the following.

1. When I access `https://example.com/app1`, it will be equivalent to accessing `http://127.0.0.1:3000`.
2. When I access `https://example.com/app1/path/within/app`, it will be equivalent to access `http://127.0.0.1:3000/path/within/app`.

However, with the above mentioned configuration file, only the first part work. If I access `https://example.com/app1/path`, my app complaints that it was `http://127.0.0.1:3000//path` that actually get accessed, and it doesn't know how to handle `//path`.

I would prefer not to modify any part of my application so that it can run independently if I decided to give it a subdomain in the future, and expects a fix with only modifying the nginx configuration file if possible. In addition, I am aware of the problem that any clickable links generated by the app will also need to handle subpath, but this app is simple enough that that is not a problem.

Thanks.

Comment: Change your location to `location ^~ /app1/  { ... }` (note the trailing slash). If you want the `/app1` URI to be workable too, add `location = /app1 { return 301 /app1/; }` to your configuration.

Comment: Thanks, are there ways to make `/app1` work without sending 301?

Comment: You can try `location = /app1 { rewrite ^ /app1/ last; }`. However in some cases it can make your app unable to load its assets (see the explanations in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70778444/7121513) answer) and I don't recommend to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following configuration

```
location /app1/ {
    proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header    Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect      off;
    proxy_pass          http://127.0.0.1:3000/;
}

location /app1 {
    return 301 /app1/;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. However, are there ways to configure it so that I don't need to send 301 when client accesses `/app1`? In other words, I would prefer redirect on server side rather than client side, if possible.

Comment: Are you sure that is what you want? Then you will have duplicate content at `http://example.com/app1` and `http://example.com/app1/` URLs, which is a problem for SEO.

Comment: The current app I am working on only provide JSON APIs, so no HTML page. However, I don't have enough experience on this topic. What is the convention if my app is an actual website? Do we generally prefer the one with trailing slashes or not? Also, how does this choice affect query parameters (those after `?`), if at all?

Comment: Query arguments are independent of the path component of a URL, so there it doesn't matter. In my own projects, I do 301 redirect from `/app1` to `/app1/`, because the one with ending slash is easier to handle in different places.

Comment: 301 with api request is bad idea, all who do this shall be sent back to modem epoch or to long ping areas, to feel that 300ms is much less than 600ms